Can I spread a TypeScript any array slice safely?
I can forward a function's arguments like this:
const log = (...args: Parameters<typeof console.log>) => {
  console.log(...args);
}

What if I want to break the arguments up?
const log = (...args: Parameters<typeof console.log>) => {
  console.log(`${this.name}: ${args[0]}`, ...args.slice(1));
}

This fails linting with:
  972:41  error  Unsafe spread of an `any` array type  @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument

Is there a right way to do this?

You receive any[] and console.log does accept any[], why not disable the rule for this usage?

The first one also fails the same rule

@VLAZ oh.  It doesn't in my config.  I'm not sure why.

@jonrsharpe ignorance mostly.  If that's the answer then fine.

“If [ignorance is] the answer than fine.” Nah, you’re not ignorant. If you’re ignorant, then I’m ignorant. You’re exploring the type system and doing interesting things, and you’re using good linter rules. That leads to correct, but sometimes unintuitive errors.
Yes, you can do what you’re asking (code examples at end):

Example 1: In the general case where you split arguments of known types, your usage example is essentially correct, except for one case: say you want to operate on the first element and then recursively pass the rest, as you’re doing here - the array could be of length zero, which would result in a TypeScript compiler error. You can handle the above safely using Tuples, coupled with Array destructuring instead of Array.slice(). Typescript accepts destructuring, because it statically (pre-runtime) assigns specific indices of the array to specific variables. TypeScript rejects slice(), because by definition it returns an arbitrary portion of the array. (To understand why, here’s something messed up: JavaScript runtime actually accepts Array.slice(NaN), or Array.slice(0, -Infinity) without throwing an error, so it would be very nonsensical for TypeScript to try to statically infer type from such an absurd function.)
Example 2:  In your specific case where you split arguments of any type, you can use the unknown type instead. TypeScript treats unknown types, unlike any types, as basically useless until their type is verified. (In your case, your linter throws an error, but without your linter, TypeScript would happily allow let a: any[] = []; let b = [...a]. However, TypeScript does allow an unknown to be passed to a function that accepts a type of any, e.g. console.log(...args: any[]).

Examples
1. General
function Input(
  a: string,
  b: number,
  c: boolean | unknown,
  ...whatever: unknown[],
) {
  // body
}

function ProcessFirst(
  a: string,
) {
  // body
}

function ProcessRest(
  b: number,
  ...whateverOrC: unknown[],
) {
  // body
}

/**
 * Because Input has three named arguments,
 * Parameter<typeof Input> gives a Tuple type:
 *
 * inputs: [
 *   string,
 *   number,
 *   boolean | unknown,
 *   ...unknown[]
 * ]
 */
const Processor = (
  ...inputs: Parameters<typeof Input>,
) => {

  // ProcessFirst: ([string]) => {}
  ProcessFirst(
    inputs[0], // OK: TypeScript knows this is string
  );

  // ProcessRest: ([number, ...unknown[]]) => {}
  // Use array destructuring to get inputs[1] and inputs.slice(2):
  const [ , b, ...whateverOrC] = inputs; // first ',' skips inputs[0]

  ProcessRest(
    b, // OK: TypeScript knows this is number
    ...whateverOrC, // OK: TypeScript knows this is [boolean | unknown, ...unknown[]]
      // -> boolean | unknown extends unknown
      // -> [boolean | unknown, ...unknown[]] extends [unknown, ...unknown[]]
      // -> [unknown, ...unknown[]] extends unknown[]
      // Therefore, whateverOrC extends unknown[]
  );

  return;
}

2. Your Case
const log = (
  ...args: [unknown, ...unknown[]]
) => {
  const [first, ...rest] = args;

  // console[`log`]: (any[]) => {}
  console.log(
    `foo: ${first}`, // OK: TypeScript knows first is unknown extends any
    ...rest, // OK: TypeScript knows rest is unknown[] extends any[]
  );
}

// log: ([unknown, ...unknown[]]) => {}
log(5, null); // OK:    [number, {}]
log(5);       // OK:    [number]
log();        // ERROR: [] 
log(...[]);   // ERROR: []

